# Manipulate Excel from Python

Tags: python, excel, com

I would like to manipulate an Excel spreadsheet from Python, e.g. open it, and execute an embedded VBA macro, or some set of actions on the data inside. I have a choice of whether I would like to work on Windows or Linux for this.

There are packages ways to do this (xlwings package from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28102695/running-excel-macro-from-python)) but I am looking for something more native to explore what options are there.

I think one way to do this is the COM interface on Windows, which xlwings itself wraps. I found win32com python module, but seem to have very little documentation on manipulating particular objects, and what methods and attributes are available. Can someone please point me to a good information source (books are also ok)?

Alternatively, are there other options to do this, and if so, where can I read up on them?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28102695/running-excel-macro-from-python

Answer (score 2):

I have gotten around this by using the Auto_Open() function in VBA, which runs when the Excel file opens.

```
Public Sub Auto_Open()
     ''' Run other macro here
End Sub
```

You could then open the Excel file using subprocess.popen.  This is a bit of a hack, but avoids using win32com.  I had to take this route because win32com wouldn't work on our locked down computers.